# Best way to design a table with m:n relation

Tags: database-design, rdbms

What is the best way to design a table for a m:n relation between two entities??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three tables.  One defining the first entity, one defining the second, and a third representing the relationship between them.

- Table 1 (first entity): T1Id, T1Name
- Table 2 (second entity): T2Id, T2Name
- Table 3 (relationship): T1Id, T2Id

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is it wrong if i use a composite key?

Comment: @r2_d2 No, you can use a composite key. Composite keys have pros and cons, but that's a different question.

Comment: @r2_d2 This *is* using a composite key, in Table 3. Since it's m:n the key is (T1Id, T2Id). If you mean something else by "use a composite key" please explain.

Comment: @philipxy I mean using both the keys as one key in the table design

Comment: @r2_d2 You seem to not be distinguishing betweeen primary/candidate key & foreign key. Is it clear to you that Table 3 *has* exactly one primary/candidate key, ie {T1Id, T2Id}, which happens to be composite?  In Table 3 each of  {T1Id} & {T2Id} are foreign keys, but not primary/candidate keys. So why did you ask if it was wrong to use a composite key, since that's what the answer has?