# Table structure for web shop

Tags: database-design

Please consider this scenario:

> A web shop sells IT products. If we look at computers and printers,
>   than there are some filters that both products need: ID, name, price,
>   e.d. Some filters are specific to only one product: OS, cartridge
>   type.

What is the best way to store these products?

1. I was thinking about this.

> Create a product table with all possible filters. If a product
>   doesn't have a certain filter, just keep it empty. This method is
>   simple to implement but can cause a lot of waisted space if there are
>   many different specific filters.

2. This is the WordPress way of doing it.

> Create a product table with only the general filters. Create a separate table which holds the meta data (specific filters) with these columns: filter_id, product_id, filter_name, filter_value. Every specific filter gets it's own row. This method doesn't waste any space, but if every product has around 10 different specific filters, than the table would become very large and might cause more performance issues than the first method.

Could someone tell me which method is the preferred way, or maybe give an alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an m:n relationship (i.e. a filter might apply to multiple products, and a product might have multiple filters) which I described here: [Best way to design a table with m:n relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29400091/best-way-to-design-a-table-with-mn-relation/29418365#29418365)

You have the extra twist of being interested in possible values.  I would recommend 4 tables:

- Table 1 has Products (ProductId, ProductName, Price etc.) list all
  possible products
- Table 2 has Filters (FilterId, FilterName etc.)
  list all possible filters (but not their possible values)
- Table 3 has the relation (ProductId, FilterId) indicating that that filter is
  appropriate for that product. FK to both Products and Filters
- Table 4 has the Filter values: (FilterId, FilterValue) FK to Filter listing
  each possible value for the given filter.

Comment: What you do is similar to what WordPress does. It seems like the best thing to do, but why do you put the values of the filters in a separate table and not in table 2 as tinytext with commas in between?

Comment: Database systems are really good at joining tables efficiently and not at parsing string comma separated values efficiently.  Basically by splitting it you're pre-parsing those csvs once and then reusing the relationship